# buttons in java, creating and using action listeners

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, applet, radio-button

im really new to eclipse and I am creating buttons for the first time. I think I have the basic idea but its not working. Anything that you can add on any part of my code is really helpful. Help! here is my code:

```
import java.applet.Applet; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 

public class MovingBox extends Applet 
{
  Thread thread; 
  Dimension dim; 
  Image img; 
  Graphics g; 
  Color red = null;
  Color blue = null;
  Font fnt16P = null;


  public void init()
  { 
    resize(800,500);    


    Button b_Up = new Button("Up"); 
    b_Up.setSize(100, 25);
    b_Up.setLocation(450,450+ 90);
    b_Up.setBackground(red); 
    b_Up.setForeground(blue);
    b_Up.setFont(fnt16P);
    b_Up.setVisible(true);
    b_Up.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
    add(b_Up);


  }

  public void paint(Graphics gfx)
  {
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(0,0,800,500);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    int value, total;;
    Object cause = event.getSource();

    if (cause == b_Up)
    (
    )

  }

}
```

Comment: What isn't working in your current code? You also need to swap the `()` for `{}` after your `if (cause == b_Up)`.

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Answer (score 2):

This code won't compile for 3 reasons:

The variable `b_Up` is not visible in `actionPerformed`. Make it a class member variable for this to work and declare it as

```
b_Up = new Button("Up");
```

You cannot have register `this` as an `ActionListener`

```
b_Up.addActionListener(this);
```

unless the class is of that type so the class needs to be declared as

```
public class MovingBox extends Applet implements ActionListener {
```

Use braces rather than parenthesis for defining the body of `if` statements:

```
if (cause == b_Up) {
   ...
}
```

Consider using the following:

- Use anonymous `ActionListener` for components. Better implementation approach
- `private` class member variables - definitely use these
- Java naming conventions recommend *camelCase* rather than Hungarian notation
- Consider using the more modern lightweight Swing libary over heavyweight AWT,

Answer (score 2):

Don't define Graphics objects. Use the Graphics object that is passed to the method.

```
Graphics g; 
...
public void paint(Graphics gfx)
  {
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(0,0,800,500);
  }
```

Don't set the size/location manually. Use a layout manager and let the layout manager do its job.

```
Button b_Up = new Button("Up"); 
b_Up.setSize(100, 25);
b_Up.setLocation(450,450+ 90);
```

I suggest you spend time learning how to use Swing instead of learning AWT. Start with the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for the basics.